Deploy OpenStack in Dell servers
I'm having a problem deploying OpenStack on a PowerEdge R710 (as a storage/control node). As I'm following the multi-node tutorial at https://ubuntu.com/openstack/install , I need to specify an un-partitioned disk with at least 200GB in sunbeam cluster bootstrap --role control,storage .
The issue is that this server uses a RAID controller that doesn't allow me to access any of the six hard drives unless they’re in a RAID configuration. I tried using LVM and creating a logical volume to pass as the argument, but I received "permission denied" errors, and I’m not sure what else to try.
I'm considering using an external drive, but that would be a really bad solution.
Is setting up a MAAS the only way to install in my situation? If not, what other options do I have?
P.S.: The other servers will also be PowerEdges and they’ll only serve as compute nodes.
